# AQGridView long press grid cell detection

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, aqgridview

I want to detect if a [AQGridCellView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/) is pressed long and instead of selecting it I want to show a menu with custom options. I thought just adding a long press gesture recognizer to a subclass of the cell view will be enough to handle that, but looks like the [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/) already catches all interactions with the cells.

Does anybody know how to workaround that and recognize a long press on the grid cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got in touch with the developer of the library and found out that this isn't possible with the library itself. But I found a simple workaround to that:

1. Disable selections in the AQGridView.
2. Create a custom grid cell and add a UITapGestureRecognizer and a UILongGestureRecognizer.
3. Instead of reacting to the AQGridViewDelegate attach to the selectors of the gesture recognizers.

This works fine for my application. Hope this solution will help somebody else too.